# Аналитическое решение однородной СЛАУ с нахождением нетривиального решения

Tags: matlab, mathematica

Матлаб помогает мне решить эту задачу на нахождение нетривиального решения СЛАУ в численном виде с помощью функции null:

```
a=[ -(dc.ge+dc.gh) dc.rh dc.re dc.gr;  
dc.gh -(dc.ge+dc.rh) 0 dc.re;  
dc.ge  0 -(dc.gh+dc.re)  dc.rh;  
0 dc.ge dc.gh -(dc.re+dc.rh+dc.gr)];  
res=null(a);
```

`
Если я использую функцию solve, то нахожу тривиальные решения системы, а именно:

```
syms x y z f k N00 N01 N10 N11 sol;  
E1 = -(x+y)*N00+f*N01+z*N10+k*N11;  
E2 = y*N00 - (x+f)*N01+z*N11;  
E3 = x*N00 - (y+z)*N10+z*N11;  
E4 = x*N01 + y*N10 - (z+f+k)*N11;  
sol=solve(E1,E2,E3,E4,N00,N01,N10,N11);
```

Есть ли способ получить **аналитическое нетривиальное** решение СЛАУ выше? Желательно в матлабе или тоже более менее дружеских несложных прикладных программ? Такое вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно. `null` работает с символьной математикой:

```
syms ge gh rh re gr
a=[ -(ge+gh) rh re gr;  
gh -(ge+rh) 0 re;  
ge  0 -(gh+re)  rh;  
0 ge gh -(re+rh+gr)];  
res=null(a)
```